# Lagrangian depending on running integral

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus, non-locality

In the theory of calculus of variations, the Lagrangian generally depends on the unknown function and its first derivative. This assumption leads to the Euler-Lagrange equations.

However, I found that many concrete problems have to be represented by a Lagrangian which also depends on the "history" of the unknown function; I would say maybe a running-integral of the unknown function, or something similar.

I searched a lot the web, but I could not find any generalization of the calculus of variation which admits this assumption (i.e. Lagrangian depending on the unknown function, its first derivative AND its previous values)

Can anybody tell me if such approach does actually exist?

Comment: These are nonlocal Lagrangians. An equation of motion can still be found by demanding stationarity. But it won't necessarily be a differential equation anymore.

Comment: What @Connor Behan says. For a simple example, see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4259962/11127) Math.SE post.